# Google maps api v3 show markers on a certain level of zoom

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm kind of a newbie in JS and google map but I'm trying to create a Styled map with my own tiles, and I want to add some markers depending on zoom level because when my map is at minZoom (0), the markers are repeating horizontally. So I'm looking for a way to disable the horizontal repeat of the markers or a way to toggle the markers depending on the level of zoom.

```
  var ItalieTypeOptions = {
    getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
        var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
        if (!normalizedCoord) {
            return null;
        }
        var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        return 'http://mysite.fr/folder' + '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' + (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.png';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    maxZoom: 4,
    minZoom: 0,
    name: 'Italie'
};
var ItalieMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(ItalieTypeOptions);

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 0,
        draggable: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        backgroundColor: '#6AAECB',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['Italie']


        }


    };




    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('Italie', ItalieMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('Italie');
    var locations = [
        ['Lorem', 20, -30],
        ['Ipsum', 20, 75],
        ['Dolor', 53, 45]
    ];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var image = {
        url: 'img/marker.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(33, 41),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),

    };




    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
            icon: image,

            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}



function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
    var y = coord.y;
    var x = coord.x;

    var tileRange = 25 << zoom;  // I wrote 25 to display only one image but i'm not ure if it's the right way

    if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
        return null;
    }

    if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
        x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
    }
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

So, I managed to display one marker depending on the level of zoom with this :

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

   var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

   if (currentZoom >= 3 && currentZoom <= 4) {
       marker.setMap(map);
       alert('lol');
   } else if (currentZoom == 0) {
       marker.setMap(null);
   } else if (currentZoom == 1) {
       marker.setMap(null);
   } else if (currentZoom == 2) {
       marker.setMap(null);
   } else if (currentZoom == 4) {
       marker.setMap(null);
   } else {
       marker.setMap(null);
   }
  });
```

I know it's not clean at all, but If someone can help me with that. The problem with this it's that it only diplay one marker (the last -> Location ['Dolor', 53, 45]), and i want to find a way to say "display all the markers in the location var)

Thanks

Comment: (And yes I have searched many times, on Stack, on google and on the google maps api documentation, but I cannot manage to disable the horizontal marker repeat)

Comment: If someone know how i can get all the markers to use them like this :

Allmarkers.setMap(map);

it will be very helpfull ^^

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for your markers, say:

```
var allMarkers = [];
```

Then when you create your markers you can push them into the array and simply run through your array to setMap(map) like so:

```
allMarkers.push(marker);
//when you are ready to display them do the loop
for(var i = 0; i <= allMarkers.length-1; i++){
    allMarkers[i].setMap(map);
}
```